# Know List of allowed actions policy for AWS Access Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

How to fetch the list of all allowed Actions for a AWS Access Key, example, how to fetch the following data for any access key:

```
{
    "Sid": "TableName",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
        "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
        "dynamodb:Get*",
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:Scan",
        "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
        "dynamodb:CreateTable",
        "dynamodb:Delete*",
        "dynamodb:Update*",
        "dynamodb:PutItem"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/MyTable"
}
```

Or I need to loop the `Action` array and check for each item?

Comment: Are you a privileged user? ie., do you have sufficient IAM privileges to list other users' policies?

Comment: No, I am not. I want to know only the policy access that are allowed for me

Answer (score 0):

You would **use AWS IAM to view the policies** associated with a given IAM User.

Please note that some services have additional policies, such as Amazon S3 bucket policies and Amazon SQS policies, which are in additional to the IAM policies.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But is is possible to do in programmatically?

Comment: You can do _everything_ on AWS programmatically. Both the programmatic SDKs and the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can retrieve details from AWS IAM.

Comment: I am a user with access policy allowing only DynamoDB actions (the ones mentioned in the question). I may or may not be having policy which allows me IAM actions. Will I be still able to list all the access allowed to me?
or I need to find it out in brute-force method by Requesting all actions in DynamoDB and check if access is allowed?

Comment: You require permissions to view permissions. (Cute, eh!) If you are purely wanting to discover your _own_ permissions, then I guess you could try lots of commands. Or, it would be easier to simply ask your administrator to tell you!

Comment: Actually designing a GUI where people with access keys can use it to perform some actions. I need to enable/disable buttons based on their allowed action policies.
So, I think the only option left for me it to check each action's authorization.